# Jacoco 0.8.8 with maven having zero code coverage with JDK17 and Sonarqube 9.9.2.77730

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, java-17, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am upgrading my spring boot microservice from Java11 to Java17, service build and run successfully with use of maven. I have added  jacoco-maven-plugin plugin for unit test cases coverage but when I tried in sonarqube I am seeing code coverage is zero. The same change is working fine with Java 11. My configuration is as below.

**Maven:** 3.6.1 
**Java:** 17.0.7 
**maven-surefire-plugin:** 2.22.2 
**jacoco-maven-plugin:** 0.8.8 
**sonarqube:** 9.9.2.77730

I am using below command for test case and coverage.

```
mvn clean test


mvn clean verify sonar:sonar \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=test-service \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
  -Dsonar.login=sqa_57657e1f59a8f2b720badb3b7b2043e004e3832f
```

Maven properties are as below:

```
<maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
<sonar.test.reportPath>coverage-reports/</sonar.test.reportPath>
<sonar.jacoco.coverage.output.directory>target/site/jacoco-ut</sonar.jacoco.coverage.output.directory>
<sonar.junit.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
<sonar.projectName>test-service</sonar.projectName>
<sonar.skip>false</sonar.skip>
```

and test profile is as below:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar-build</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
            <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Jacoco prepare-agent builds some command-line params without -->
                        <!-- which jacoco will not instrument. Hence it is important to add -->
                        <!-- those command-line params here (${argLine} holds those params) -->
                        <argLine>${surefireArgLine} -Xms256m -Xmx2048m</argLine>
                        <argLine>
                            --add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens java.base/java.time.format=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens java.base/java.util.stream=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                        </argLine>
                        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                        <runOrder>random</runOrder>
                        <destFile>${sonar.test.reportPath}</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                        <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-report</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${sonar.jacoco.coverage.output.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: On my system, Jacoco runs fine without any of those `--add-opens` options. I can’t even imagine why Jacoco should require such options.

Comment: First determine whether the problem is with Jacoco or SonarQube. You should have a directory in "target" where it is writing your Jacoco output files. If Jacoco ran, there should be an "index.html" file.  Open that file in your browser. Inspect the results.  If they look too low (or zero), then the problem is in your Jacoco configuration. If they are fine, then SonarQube isn't getting the Jacoco data.